# Shell loses keypresses when running SSH in the background

Tags: ssh, terminal, terminal.app

I'm experiencing a bizarre problem with SSH + Bash + Terminal.app: when SSH is run in the background, the shell appears to randomly lose keypresses ~50% of the time.

For example, if I run:

```
$ ssh -N my-tunnel &
$ # typing becomes lossy
```

Then type "asdf", only the letters "a" and "f" might show up (although this is random and partially related typing speed; if I was typing at full speed, possibly only the "f" might appear).

This problem only affects the shell. If I run, for example, `ssh -N my-tunnel & cat`, characters are echoed as expected from cat. Key presses are lost once cat is killed and I'm back at the shell.

Other things to note:

- Other terminal windows are unaffected
- The shell returns to normal as soon as ssh is terminated
- Using `nohup ssh -N my-tunnel &` doesn't change anything

So: what's going on here? And is there any way I can background ssh without breaking the terminal?

Answer (score 4):

You should be using `-n` in addition to `-N` to prevent ssh from reading from the terminal.

Comment: Bad idea: if `ssh` needs a password, it won't work. See my answer.

Comment: Well, if he's running it with &, ssh obviously does not need a password.

Comment: That's precisely why `&` is a bad idea. The `-f` option has been designed to take care of passwords. Using this option is the right solution, which works in all cases.

Comment: Unfortunately `-f` doesn't play well with `ControlPersist`. When using `ssh -fN` the connection is closed after `ControlPersist` seconds.

Answer (score 3):

This is the normal behavior. Do not run `ssh` in background when it is still connected to the terminal. If you want to put it in background once the terminal is no longer needed (e.g. for a password), use the `-f` option and do not use `&`:

```
ssh -fN my-tunnel
```

Comment: The difficulty with using `-f` is that the connection is closed after a timeout of `ConnectionPersist` :/

Comment: @DavidWolever I suppose that you mean `ControlPersist`, but where do you see that this is specific to `-f`?

Comment: Err, yes, I mean `ControlPersist`. It's relevant to `-f` because, `ControlPersist` seconds after running `ssh -fN`, the connection is closed. If I remove `ControlPersist` the connection isn't closed.